# Scraping Basico en Java con Jsoup

Tags: java, html, netbeans, jsoup

Tengo un formulario simple de esta manera

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>INICIO</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center">
    <legend>INGRESO</legend>
    <form action="evaluar.php" method="post">
        <label>NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtnombre"><br>
        <label>APELLIDO</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtapellido"><br>
    <select name="cbonivel"> 
        <option value="Secundaria">Secundaria</option>
        <option value="Primaria">Primaria</option>
        <option  value="Seleccione" selected>Seleccione un nivel</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="btningresar">

    </form>

</div>
```

De Esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para Obtener Los datos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como obtendria esos datos en JAVA

```
 public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

       Document docu=Jsoup.connect("http://localhost/SCRAPING/inicio.html").data("txtnombre","JOSE")
               .data("txtapellido","CASTILLO").userAgent("Mozilla").post();

       System.out.println(docu);  
        }
```

}
Si me podrian ayudar por favor

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la herramienta Selenium

```
public class RobotSelenium {
private WebDriver robot;

public RobotSelenium() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/andy/NetBeansProjects/librerias/selenium/geckodriver");
    robot= new FirefoxDriver();
}

private String abriendoPagina(String direccionWeb){        
 robot.get(direccionWeb);

 String pageSource = robot.getPageSource(); // aqui se almacena toda la informacion de la pagina. Luego se puede crear cualquier metodo de busqueda dentro del String

 robot.close();

 return pageSource;
}  }
```